# How to Select everything up to and including the 3rd slash (RegExp)?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

What would be the easiest RegExp selecting all before the 3rd slash?

I tried this:

```
([^\/?#]+){3}(?:.*?\/)
```

But it does not work exactly as I would hope it would do. What's more I don't know that it will work in Google Analytics (Filter Section)

I would like it to match:

1. `/`
2. `/news/`
3. `/news/details/`

Everything more than this (after the 3rd slash) is not what I want to get

Answer (score 2):

In your comment, you give three examples: `/`, `/news/` and `/news/details/`. Based on these examples, here is a solution:

`^(\/[^\/]*){1,2}\/?`

It says: from the start of the string match the following:

- a slash, then zero or more non-slashes
- optionally followed by a second slash plus zero or more non-slashes
- optionally followed by a final slash

[image: test-output]

Answer (score 1):

What you might do instead is ot repeat matching 2 times not a forward slash and then a forward slash.

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}[^\/]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aeO093/1)

If you don't want to match `?#` you could add that to the character class

```
^(?:[^\/?#]*\/){2}[^\/]+
```

About your pattern

This part of your pattern `([^\/?#]+){3}` captures in a group matching 1+ times any character that is not in the character class but after that repetition takes no forward slash into account.

Then `(?:.*?\/)` will match any character non greedy followed by a forward slash.

Comment: It does not work (as it comes to GA). When there are some parameters (?) or hashes (#) in the Request URI it returns '//'

Comment: @MattMatt Can you give an example of what should match and what should not match?