# How to use regex to match upto third forward slash in R using gsub?

Tags: r, regex

So this question is relating to specifically how R handles regex - I would like to find some regex in conjunction with gsub to extract out the text all but before the 3rd forward slash.

Here are some string examples:

```
/google.com/images/video 
/msn.com/bing/chat
/bbc.com/video
```

I would like to obtain the following strings only:

```
/google.com/images
/msn.com/bing
/bbc.com/video
```

So it is not keeping the information after the 3rd forward slash.

I cannot seem to get any regex working along with using gsub to solve this!

The closest I have got is:

```
gsub(pattern = "/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]*$", replacement = "", x = the_data_above )
```

I think R has some issues regarding forward slashes and escaping them.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002107/regexp-select-everything-before-the-3rd-slash

Comment: If you are not concerned with the # of slashes and just want everything before the last slash you could use `dirname()`

Comment: @Andrew Not what i need - I need it to stop after a certain slash

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `gsub("(/.+?/.+?)/.*", "\\1", text)`

Comment: @Andrew haha this is it! thanks man thats it!

Comment: `gsub` does not extract, it *replaces*. Use `stringr::str_extract` to make your life easier when extracting regex matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the start of the string match two instances of slash and following non-slash characters followed by anything and replace with the two instances.

```
paths <- c("/google.com/images/video", "/msn.com/bing/chat", "/bbc.com/video")
sub("^((/[^/]*){2}).*", "\\1", paths)
## [1] "/google.com/images" "/msn.com/bing"      "/bbc.com/video"
```

Comment: can i retain the slash after the word bing so it returns /msn.com/bing/ in the output?

Comment: `sub("^((/[^/]*){2}/?).*", "\\1", paths)`

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of lazy (vs greedy) matching by adding the `?` after the quantifier (`+` in this case) within your capture group:

```
gsub("(/.+?/.+?)/.*", "\\1", text)
[1] "/google.com/images" "/msn.com/bing"      "/bbc.com/video"
```

**Data**:

```
text <- c("/google.com/images/video",
"/msn.com/bing/chat",
"/bbc.com/video")
```

Comment: can i retain the slash after the word bing? is that possible?

Comment: Sure thing, just change the pattern to `"(/.+?/.+?/?).*"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
^\/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+
```

As seen here: https://regex101.com/r/9ZYppe/1

Your problem arises from the fact that `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]` matches only **one** such character. You need to use the `+` operator to specify that there are multiple of them. Also, the `$` at the end is pretty unnecessary because using `^` to assert the start of the sentence solves a great many problems.

Comment: I can't seem to extract the strings using this code in R - it seemingly only extracts the information after the 3rd slash

Comment: @BeansOnToast It might be because the `.` hasn't been escaped. Try this: `^\/[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]+`

Comment: Nope - when using this code `gsub(pattern = "^\\/[A-Za-z0-9_\\.-]+\\/[A-Za-z0-9_\\.-]+",x = t, replacement = "")` it should replace those things after the third slash with a blank character but it is not - is there an alternative way to do this instead?